# ClassCastException unable to cast Writable to Text

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I created a subclass called TextArrayWritable to hold an array of Text. It looks like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable{
    public TextArrayWritable() {
        super(Text.class);
    }
    public TextArrayWritable(Text[] values) {
        super(Text.class,values);
    }
}
```

In my mapper, I produce a key-value pair, where the key is a Text, and the value is the above TextArrayWritable. The code for the mapper is as seen below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class TagWordMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,TextArrayWritable>{
    
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        if(key.get()==0) {
            return;
        }else {
            String line = value.toString();
            Text title = new Text(line.split("\t")[2]);
            Text likes =  new Text(line.split("\t")[8]);
            Text tags =  new Text(line.split("\t")[6]);
            
            Text[] temp = new Text[2];
            temp[0]=likes;
            temp[1]=tags;
            
            context.write(title, new TextArrayWritable(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the reducer, when I loop through the TextArrayWritable, the exception occurs even though I have casted it as Text[] as the TextArrayWritable#get() returns the array of Text. The reducer code is as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class TagWordCombiner extends Reducer<Text,TextArrayWritable,Text,IntWritable>{

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text title,Iterable<TextArrayWritable> arrays,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int count=0;
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\bcute\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        for(TextArrayWritable array:arrays) {
            
            Text[] temp = (Text[]) array.get();
            int likes = Integer.parseInt(temp[0].toString());
            String tags = temp[1].toString();
            
            Matcher matcher = r.matcher(tags);
            boolean found = matcher.find();
            if(found && likes>=3000){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
        context.write(title, new IntWritable(count));
    }
}
```

Any idea why it is happening even when I have casted the return type as Text[]. Any insight is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not use TextArrayWritable and just opted to send in arrays of data in string form using Text. Furthermore, I discovered that for Combiners to work. The input/output datatype of the Combiner must match the output datatype of the Mapper.

Here's my code:

Mapper:

```
package combiner;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class CombinerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        if(key.get()==0) {
            return;
        }else {
            String line = value.toString();
            Text title = new Text(line.split("\t")[2]);
            Text arr = new Text(line.split("\t")[8]+"\t"+line.split("\t")[6]);
            context.write(title, arr);
        }
        
    }
}
```

What it does, it maps a `.csv` file. It skips the first line because the first line are headers and not useful. In the next line, it splits by "\t" to extract the 'title','likes','tags', in that order. Only the 'likes' and 'tags' are to be inserted into the array. The Mapper output data type is Text,Text.

Combiner:

```
package combiner;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CombinerCombiner extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text title,Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum=0;
        for(Text val:values) {
            String line = val.toString();
            int likes = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\t")[0]);
            String tags = line.split("\t")[1];
            
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\bcute\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = r.matcher(tags);
            boolean found = matcher.find();
            
            if(found && likes>=3000) {
                sum+=1;
            }
        }
        if(sum==0) {
            return;
        }else {
            context.write(title, new Text(Integer.toString(sum)));
        }
    }
}
```

The tricky thing to how the combiner works is that its input/output must match the output data type of the Mapper or it will throw the error I encountered. I use the combiner in this case as a filter, to filter out titles that do not have >=3000 likes and its tags does not contain the word cute, in any form. It inputs as <Text,Text> datatype and outputs as <Text,Text> datatype, both same as the output data type of the Mapper.

Finally, the Reducer:

```
package combiner;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class CombinerReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,IntWritable>{

    public void reduce(Text title,Iterable<Text>counts,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int sum = 0;
        for(Text count:counts) {
            String line = count.toString();
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(line);
            sum+=temp;
        }
        context.write(title, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
```

It functions as regular Reducer,it sums the arrays of data and produce a final sum. It is quite pointless to loop through the Iterable since it is done for us in the combiner, but it works.

Here's my driver class:

```
package combiner;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class Combiner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Check if proper arguments is inputed
        if (args.length != 2) {
              System.out.printf(
                  "Usage: TagWord <input dir> <output dir>\n");
              System.exit(-1);
        }
        
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(Combiner.class);
        job.setJobName("Combiner");
        
        //Declare the input file path
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        
        //Declare the output file path
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        
        //Initiate the the -cers
        job.setMapperClass(CombinerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(CombinerCombiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CombinerReducer.class);
        
        //map output
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
        //reducer output
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        
        //Initiate boolean to check whether MapReduce is successful
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        
        //Execute code based on whether the job is successful
        System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Notice the combiner class, in between the mapper and reducer class. Also, ensure to include setMapOutputKeyClass and setMapOutputValueClass. This is allows for different output datatype for Mapper class. It also forces the reducer output datatype to be whatever you set for setOutputKeyClass and setOutputValueClass, in our case, our reducer must output Text and IntWritable.

If there's any questions, do comment. Information for Hadoop is kinda scarce.